# Using gmail api suspends an user account due to "Request limits"

Tags: gmail-api

Our application processes emails for clients. One client very often became "suspended". In GSuite Admin console he saw that he have hit "Requests limit". At the same time as gmail web interface is suspended, gmail mobile is working. Our application also do not see any interruption. We do not see nor '429 Too Many Requests "Too many concurrent requests for user"' nor '429 Too Many Requests "User-rate limit exceeded"' nor any other kind of errors.

Therefore, the user became suspended from time to time due to "request limit", we do not see any rejected requests due to limits/quotas. We do not do concurrent requests per user. That is, different users are processed concurrently but processing for one user is sequential. But we also use batching, biggest batch size is 20.

On a page about "[Request limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1359240)" I found only that "the number of server requests a G Suite account can make at one time is limited". What does "one time" mean? Does batching make the issue worse or it helps? Do other apis (ex. Calendar api) counted here? Is gmail mobile counted here? Is there any way to get support for such question?

Any help is aprecated.

PS. Most calls to Gmail are `history.list`, `messages.get` (with max batch size is 5), `threads.get` (max batch size is 20). Calls of `messages.attachments.get` (max batch size is 2) are not so often. `history.list` and `messages.get` are called as new messages arrived to user mailbox. Sometimes `messages.get` and `threads.get` bursts. But we have a code to prevent getting out of quotas. Attachments are processed by 2, one batch (of 2) in 5 seconds, but we are going to slow it down to 1 attachment per 5 secs. In my opinion, the rate is low (per one user). Also the app calls other apis - gdrive api, calendar api, old contacts api. 
We see 429 code very very rare. But one our client suffers from suspensions 1-2 times a week. Sometimes a suspension lasts for about 1 hour, sometimes a suspension is a sequence of several short periods of time

Comment: "one time" here would mean 'the time you make an API call/request'. [Batching Requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) is a good way to reduce your quota - so nothing but positive here. It would be nice to include which calls are you making and how often? Maybe too many write requests?

Comment: Most calls to Gmail are `history.list`, `messages.get` (with max batch size is 5), 'threads.get' (max batch size is 20).  Calls 
 of "messages.attachments.get" (max batch size is 2) are not so often.

Comment: `history.list` and `messages.get` are called as new messages arrived to user mailbox. Sometimes `messages.get` and `threads.get` bursts.  But we have a code to prevent getting out of [https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota]quotas.  Attachments are processed by 2, one batches (of 2) in 5 seconds, but we are going to slow it down to 1 attachment per 5 secs. In my opinion, the rate is low (per one user). Also, the app calls other apis - gdrive api, calendar api, old contacts api.

Comment: We see 429 code very very rare. But one our client suffers from suspensions 1-2 times a week. Sometimes a suspension lasts for about 1 hour, sometimes a suspension is a sequence of several short periods of time.

Comment: the only solution i can suggest is to slowdown on requests. apparently, your app is making requests that's too much for the Google server to process at a time.

Comment: I see. Thank you! 
Note on batching: I asked about quota efficiency of batches because I have seen when first 4 queries of one batch resulted in "429 Rate Limit Exceeded", and last query (to same api endpoint) in the batch was successful. From that I concluded that batches are good to reduce communication overhead, and not so good for dealing with quotas/limits.